# Append more than once with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can I append my variable `form` to the `container` more than once on click of the button? I have 3 append statements in the click event and it only appends once. I would expect 3 `form`s per click to be appended.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsm2xbdt/1/)

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  var form = $('.form').first().clone();
  $('.container').append(form);
  $('.container').append(form);
  $('.container').append(form);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>
      Click
      </button>
  <div class="form">
    Hello, World
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `outerHTML` to append the content all times you need. The `clone()` function creates only a copy.

https://jsfiddle.net/843yhrqs/

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  var form = $('.form')[0].outerHTML;
  $('.container').append(form);
  $('.container').append(form);
  $('.container').append(form);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>
      Click
      </button>
  <div class="form">
    Hello, World
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to `clone()` the form each time, otherwise jQuery seems to detect that you've already appended the same object before.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  var form = $('.form').first().clone();
  $('.container').append(form);
  $('.container').append(form.clone());
  $('.container').append(form.clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>
      Click
      </button>
  <div class="form">
    Hello, World
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

An element can't appear in multiple places at the same time.

You've only cloned it once.

Clone it each time instead.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button', function() {
  var form = $('.form').first();
  $('.container').append(form.clone());
  $('.container').append(form.clone());
  $('.container').append(form.clone());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>
      Click
      </button>
  <div class="form">
    Hello, World
  </div>
</div>
```